# Buscar valores anómalos en una matriz en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy empezando a estudiar el lenguaje c y necesito un poco de ayuda con este ejercicio.

Está casi todo hecho y solo falta compilarlo y ver si funciona, pero no estoy muy segura de como hacer la última parte.

Cuando se elige la opción 4 del menú, el programa debe hacer un recorrido de la matriz (creo que es un recorrido) y comprobar si existen valores en la primera columna que sean superiores a 1, en la segunda columna que sean superiores a 0.2 y en la tercera columna que sean superiores a 0.02. Si encuentra estos valores aparecera un mensaje que indica que hay al menos un valor anómalo, de lo contrario, aparecerá un mensaje indicando que los valores que has introducido son correctos.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMPIPETAS 3
#define MAXMEDICIONES 5

void leerMediciones(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);
void imprimirMediciones(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);
void calcularPromedio (int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);
void calcularDesviacionTipica(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);
void calcularErrorAleatorio(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);
void buscarAnomalos(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);

void main(){

    int matriz[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES];
    int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES], sumaColumnas[NUMPIPETAS];
    float x[15];
    int opc=0;
    char choice;

    do {
        leerMediciones(m);
        system("cls");

        printf("-----------MENU-----------\n\n");
        printf("1.- Introducir las mediciones\n");
        printf("2.- Imprimir mediciones\n");
        printf("3.- Calcular error aleatorio\n");
        printf("4.- Buscar valores anomalos\n");
        printf("0.- Salir\n\n");
        printf("Elige una opcion: ");

        scanf("%d",&opc);
        printf("----------------------------\n");

        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1: leerMediciones(matriz);
                    break;

            case 2: imprimirMediciones(matriz);
                    break;

            case 3: calcularPromedio (matriz);
                    calcularDesviacionTipica(matriz);
                    calcularErrorAleatorio(matriz);
                    break;

            case 4: buscarAnomalos(matriz);
                    break;

            default:printf("Opcion no valida. Por favor, vuelva a elegir. \n");
        }
      }while(choice !=4);

        imprimirMatriz(matriz);
     }

void leerMediciones(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]){

    int i,j;

    printf("Introduzca los elementos de la matriz %dx%d\n",NUMPIPETAS,MAXMEDICIONES);//deberia poner aqui i y j en vez de numpipetas y maxmediciones??

      for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){
          for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){

            printf("Fila %d - Columna %d: ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
         }
      }
}

void imprimirMediciones(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]){

    int i,j;
    printf("Impresion de la Matriz:\n");

       for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){
           for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){
               printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
           }
                printf("\n");
       }
}

void calcularPromedio (int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]){

   int i,j;
   float sumaTotal, sumaColumnas[NUMPIPETAS], suma, media;
/*Ahora calculamos la media*/
/*Pero primero hacemos la suma total*/

    sumaTotal=0;

     for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){
            sumaTotal = sumaTotal + m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES];
                     }
                }

            /*Calculamos la suma de cada columna*/
                for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){
                    suma = 0;

                    for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){
                        suma = suma + m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES];
                    }

                  sumaColumnas[j] = suma;

            /*Ahora hacemos la media de cada columna*/
                  media = suma/5;
                }
}

void calcularDesviacionTipica(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]){

   int i,j;
   float suma1=0, media, varianza, desviacion_tipica;
   int x[i];
/*Calculamos la desviacion tipica*/

    for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){
                {
                 suma1 = suma1 + pow((media - x[i]), 2);
                }
        }
    }

    varianza = suma1 / 4;
    desviacion_tipica = sqrt(varianza);
        printf("Desviacion tipica = %.2f\n", desviacion_tipica);
        getch();
}

void calcularErrorAleatorio(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]){

   float error_aleatorio, desviacion_tipica;
    error_aleatorio = desviacion_tipica/sqrt(5);
        printf("Error aleatorio = %.2f\n", error_aleatorio);
        getch();
}

void buscarAnomalos(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]){
    //buscar numeros mayores que 1 en la primera columna
    //mayores que 0.2 en la segunda columna y que 0.02 en la tercera columna
 int i,j;

/*Vamos a hacer un recorrido para calcular los valores anomalos*/
    for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){
         for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){
            if
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Para insertar el código introduce 4 ó 5 espacios en blanco delante. 2) El sitio es para preguntas específicas. Analiza el programa, encuentra el sitio donde lo que pasa es distinto a lo que esperas y pon sólo el código necesario para esa parte del programa. Explica también qué es lo que esperas que haga y qué es lo que está sucediendo.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so] Marta. Como dice Sjuan para formatear el código se usan 4 espacios en blanco (seleciona todo tu código y pulsa Ctrl + k o en el simbolo `{ }` del editor). Puedes mirarte [Ayuda de edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para más información.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con la tercera columna? Realmente tu sólo tienes filas y columnas (matriz bidimensional). ¿O te refieres a las tres primeras columnas de la primera fila?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que leo, ¿ya lo tienes casi todo hecho no? No entiendo que dificultad le ves ahí. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es dentro del bucle anidado de buscarAnomalos() es mirar si i es la primera, segunda o tercera columna, y en función de eso mirar si el valor es mayor a los que has dicho.

```
//primera columna
if(i==0 && m[j][i]>1){
   //Valor anómalo
}
//segunda columna
if(i==1 && m[j][i]>0.2){
   //Valor anómalo
}
//tercera columna
if(i==2 && m[j][i]>0.02){
   //Valor anómalo
}
```

Y esos serian los tres casos creo. dentro de los comentarios, deberías añadir tu implementación para tratar lo que ocurre en caso de encontrar el valor anómalo.

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que en la definición de la función...

```
void buscarAnomalos(int m[NUMPIPETAS][MAXMEDICIONES]);
```

... está incompleta, deberías agregar:

```
/*Vamos a hacer un recorrido para calcular los valores anomalos*/
for(j=0;j<MAXMEDICIONES;j++){
      for(i=0;i<NUMPIPETAS;i++){

       /*Esto es nuevo*/
       if(i == 0 && m[i][j] > 1){
        /*Número anómalo*/
        printf("Número mayor a 1 en la primera columna"); 
       }
       if(i == 1 && m[i][j] > 0.2){
        /*Número anómalo*/
        printf("Número mayor a 0.2 en la Segunda columna"); 
       }
       if(i == 2 && m[i][j] > 0.02){
        /*Número anómalo*/
        printf("Número mayor a 0.02 en la tercera columna"); 

        /*FIN DE LO NUEVO*/
       }
     }
}
printf("La matriz está correcta");
```

Personalmente daría vuelta los `for`, recorrería primero por columna y después por fila.

Dentro de los `if` tendrías que colocar tu implementación.

Answer (score 0):

fijate las dimensiones al declarar ,dar vuelta los indices y podrias hacer esto:

for(i=0;i

```
   if( m[i][j] > 1){
    printf("Número mayor a 1 en la primera columna"); 
   }
   else
     if(m[i][j] > 0.2){
    printf("Número mayor a 0.2 en la Segunda columna"); 
   }
   else 
    printf("Número mayor a 0.02 en la tercera columna"); 
   }
```

corregi errores y mejore la sintaxis